# How to get nanoseconds since epoch for string formatted time "2019-01-25 14:34:34.123456789" in java?

Tags: java, time, datetime-conversion

I am able to parse `2019-01-25 14:34:34.123456789` string and get the object of `ZonedDateTime`.
Now, I want to get time in nanoseconds precision level since epoch from this `ZonedDateTime` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) might help:

Something like:

```java
Duration.between(
  ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.EPOCH, ZoneId.of("UTC")),
  yourZonedDatetime
).toNanos()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work until year 2262:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 25, 14, 34, 34, 123456789)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    Instant i = zdt.toInstant();
    long epochNano = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(i.getEpochSecond(), TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)),
            i.getNano());
    System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(epochNano));
```

Output:

> 1,548,407,074,123,456,789

Why I am not just using `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(i.getEpochSecond())` is in case of overflow this would just give me `Long.MAX_VALUE`, that is, an incorrect result. `Math.multiplyExact` will throw an exception in case of overflow, so we will discover, which I clearly prefer.

To avoid overflow in year 2262 and later use `BigInteger`:

```
    BigInteger epochNano = BigInteger.valueOf(i.getEpochSecond())
            .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1)))
            .add(BigInteger.valueOf(i.getNano()));
```

The result is the same.

Pros and cons: There’s a little more handwork in my code than in the code by Slawomir Chodnicki, which is certainly a disadvantage. On the other hand I didn’t find the use of `Duration` very well motivated here either, and that will not work after year 2262 either (throws an `ArithmeticException`). The perfect solution doesn’t exist.